# context.getCachedir() and Environment getConDownloadCacheDirectory android

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Are `context.getCachedir()` and Environment `getConDownloadCacheDirectory` same?

I am implementing bitmap caching and confused which one to use.
If i use the context one then it we will need to hold the reference to the context and that might cause memory leaks.
So which one to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is difference.

context.getCachedir() =   /data/data/your.application.package/cache (this is a absolute path)

Environment.getConDownloadCacheDirectory() = /cache (this is relative path)